# Jooq limit before join

Tags: java, jooq

I have two tables with a 1-n relation, i.e. a table Order which stores orders and a table OrderPosition which stores positions of an order.

When fetching from the DB while joining both tables I want to limit the number of orders. When limiting after the join of the two tables, this will obviously not work, as one order may result multiple records depending on the number of the positions the order has.

This is what I wrote with Jooq now:

```
    final Table<Record> alias = context.select().from(ORDER).limit(1).asTable();

    final Result<Record> result =
        context
            .select()
            .from(alias.join(ORDER_POSITION)
                .on(ORDER_POSITION.ORDER_ID.eq(alias.field(ORDER.ID))))
            .fetch();
```

This does not seem to limit the number of orders, it returns me more than one order. On the other hand, if I replace the join with a leftJoin, the limitation works just as intended (also for different limit parameters). I used a H2 DB to test the query (not sure if it matters).

I'm aware of the difference of join and leftJoin but should the limitation work in both cases as intended or did I miss something?

This is what is generated by Jooq with a join:

```
select 
  "alias_129458832"."ID", 
  "alias_129458832"."KEY", 
  ...
  "PUBLIC"."ORDER_POSITION"."ID", 
  "PUBLIC"."ORDER_POSITION"."ORDER_ID"
from (
  select 
    "PUBLIC"."ORDER"."ID", 
    "PUBLIC"."ORDER"."KEY", 
    ...
  from "PUBLIC"."ORDER"
  limit ?
) "alias_129458832"
  join "PUBLIC"."ORDER_POSITION"
    on "PUBLIC"."ORDER_POSITION"."ORDER_ID" = 
    "alias_129458832"."ID"
```

If I replace the query with a leftJoin, it generates the same query except the join is replaced by 'left outer join'.

**What I tested**

I run the tests with an in-memory H2 database. I have a couple of orders without any positions, one order with one position and one order with three positions.

With the join and a limit of 1, I got all 4 joined records (which means it returns both orders), with a limit of 0 I got no records. The order has a random key, which is always randomly generated for each test. If I order the orders by this key with

```
context.select().from(ORDER).orderBy(ORDER.KEY).limit(4).asTable();
```

and a limit of 4 I got sometimes no records, sometimes one record (the order with one position), sometimes three records (the order with three positions) and sometimes all 4 records (which is both orders).

As mentioned if I replace the join with a leftJoin, I got also of course the orders without any position and but here the number of orders specified with the limit is always correct.

Comment: What exactly didn't work with your approach? It looks correct. What's the SQL query that was generated?

Comment: I edited my answer and tried to add more infos. If it helps I use Jooq 3.13.1. I can try to replace the H2 in memory database with in memory HSQLDB to see if it behaves the same.

Comment: So, everything works as expected, no? What kind of result are you expecting? Perhaps you can post that here?

Comment: No, if I have a limit of 1 with the mentioned test data, it returns 4 joined records, which are both orders (the one with one positions and the one with three positions). I expect here to get only one order. Also if I order by the key and set a limit of 4, I expect to get both orders, but I got sometimes only one or no order at all. Or is my expectation wrong?

Comment: I'd have to be able to reproduce this with example data... Might as well be an esoteric bug in H2.

Comment: I'll see if I can create a minimal example based on my current project to reproduce this behaviour which I can share.